# AJAX working locally but not on Server

Tags: javascript, ajax

Error i am getting when running on server :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
```

I am using AJAX to retrieve XML from a PHP file and place the response in my HTML div.
Javascript file is for creating the AJAX object and handing server response.

When i run this code locally, everything is working fine. 
What is going wrong? I am only uploading the same files to the server so it should work there as well?

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';

echo '<response>';

$food      = $_GET['food']; //GET/POST to send the data (code to send data inside js file)
$foodArray = array(
    'tuna',
    'bacon',
    'beef',
    'meat'
);

if (in_array($food, $foodArray))
    echo 'We do have ' . $food;

elseif ($food == '')
    echo "AJAX. Server response will be displayed here";
else
    echo 'Sorry! We don\'t sell ' . $food;
echo '</response>';
?>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}



function process() {
    if (xmlHttp) {
        try {
            food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);

            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;

            xmlHttp.send(null);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 100);
    }
}



function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            try {
                xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
                xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement; // Root element of XML file.
                message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data; //Cox it is the only child in the xml document. Data - Output of XML content. So now, message contains the O/P of php.
                document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = message; //Now that we got the echo statement from the server, we want to store it in our div.            
                //innerHTML - The html in between the div. The stuff that shows on the web page :)
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.toString());
            }
            setTimeout('process()', 100);

        } else {
            alert(xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="process();">
<div>
Enter a food item you would like to search: e.g. bacon<br>
<input type="text" id="userInput"/><br>
<br>
<div id="underInput"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- AJAX requests for XML files should use the *application/javascript* mime/media type, there is no such thing as "text/xml".

  `header('Content-Type: application/xml');`
- The first element in the AJAX request needs to have an XML namespace...

  `<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></div>`
- You don't send an XML declaration for AJAX requests, *just* full-page requests.
- Download a copy of Fiddler2, preferably an older version (2.2.9.1 still has the text label on the remove button, newer is not always better) where you can see the HTTP status codes.
- Watch your Apache access log as well to see where requests are going.
- Always `alert()` yurself to what is going on...

---

This code is in a REUSABLE AJAX script, pass the parameter 'id_container_pos' to choose HOW XML is AJAX-loaded on to the page...

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {try {xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');} catch (e) {try {xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');} catch (e) {}}}
else {alert('Error: Your browser does not seem to support AJAX.');}
xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState=='4')
 {
  //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  //If you have an element with a 'body' ID that is all lowercase, this is IE8 versus good browsers...
  if (!document.getElementById('Body') && xmlhttp.responseXML) {var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;}
  else {var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseText;}

  if (id_container_pos=='after') {id_container_obj.insertBefore(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],id_container_obj.nextSibling);}
  else if (id_container_pos=='before')
  {
   id_container_obj.parentNode.insertBefore(document.importNode(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],true),id_container_obj);
   }
  else if (id_container_pos=='inside') {id_container_obj.appendChild(document.importNode(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],true));}
  else if (id_container_pos=='replace') {var r = id_container_obj.parentNode; r.removeChild(r.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]); r.appendChild(document.importNode(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],true));}
 }
}
```

---

Comment: OK! I changed the header line from the php file.
Your second bullet point; where should i add this div?
3rd point: Are you saying i should remove

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'; 

from the php file?

Because i did. And still it gives the same error.

Comment: The first <element> be whatever it may be *must* have an XML namespace `attribute="value"` (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"). You need to understand the generic terms used to refer to `<element attribute="value" attribute="value">` otherwise you would not have guessed what I had clearly stated and you'll catch on faster. Correct: you do not use the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` for AJAX loaded content, just the main page itself. Do not use `documentElement` and **NEVER** use innerHTML.

Comment: Your div confused me. I just want to know why it is not working on the server for my own knowledge. Even if i do everything as you mentioned, it is again working locally but not on server.

Comment: The `div` element is a generic block-level element, it is important to understand the semantics of HTML elements. If the server isn't working then it's the different environment with different facts that you need to look in to. My platform makes handling local/live environments work without having to tweak much because of the difference. I recommend using Fiddler2 to view HOW the request is being handled and WHERE it is being sent to.